# Importing Extended Event results to a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell

I’m implementing a new process to audit successful and failed SQL Server logins by utilizing the Extended Events feature.  I’ve already setup Extended Events to monitor successful and failed logins with their results being sent to an .xel file.  However, querying these .xel files to view the data seems quite cumbersome.  It would be best to have the .xel file data imported into a SQL Server table.  I’ve found a PowerShell script (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/PowerShell/160582/) that can be used to import the data, but I’m having issues getting it to work.  I setup a test Extended Event to monitor rpc_completed and sql_batch_completed events, which I believe will show what t-sql statements have been run and the users that ran them.  The script below was written specifically for those events and is designed to import the data as I’ve explained, but I cannot get it to work.

Does anyone know why my PowerShell script is unable to load the Microsoft.SqlServer.XE.Core.dll assembly?

Here’s my script –

```
########Powershell cmdlet to load XE#######



 Function Shred-XElogs{
  param(
  [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string] $filewithPath,
  [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string] $servername,
  [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string] $fileName
  )
  Try
  {
  #Load the required assemblies
  $dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 

Server\120\Shared\Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll"
      if(([appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | Where {$_.Location -match "Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll"}) -eq $null)
       {
         Write-Host "Assembly not found. Loading it from $dllpath" `r`n
         [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath)
       }
  else
       {
        write-host "Assembly is already loaded." `r`n
       }
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath)
  #create data table
  $dt = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
  #Define Columns
  $server_name = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'server_name',([string])
  $xe_load_date = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'xe_load_date',([DateTime])
  $start_date = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'start_date',([DateTime])
  $end_time = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'end_time',([datetime])
  $text_data = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'text_data',([string])
  $duration = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'duration',([int64])
  $logicalreads = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'logicalreads',([int64])
  $physicalreads = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'physicalreads',([int])
  $EndResult = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'EndResult',([int])
  $RowCount = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'RowCount',([int])
  $ObjectName = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'ObjectName',([string])
  $writes = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'writes',([int])
  $CPU = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'CPU',([int64])
  $event_name = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'event_name',([string])
  $database_id = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'database_id',([int])
  $hostname = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'hostname',([string])
  $application_name = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'application_name',([string])
  $login_name = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'login_name',([string])
  $hostname = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'hostname',([string])
  $spid = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'spid',([int])
  $xe_log_file = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'xe_log_file',([string])
  # create columns
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($server_name)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($xe_load_date)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($start_date)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($end_time)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($text_data)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($duration)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($logicalreads)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($physicalreads)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($EndResult)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($RowCount)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($ObjectName)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($writes)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($CPU)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($event_name)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($database_id)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($hostname)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($application_name)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($login_name)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($spid)
  [void]$dt.Columns.Add($xe_log_file)
  $events = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.QueryableXEventData($filewithPath)
  $events | % {
      $currentEvent = $_
  $row = $dt.NewRow()
  $audittime = Get-Date
  $row.server_name = $servername
  $row.xe_load_date = [DateTime] $audittime
  $row.end_time = $currentEvent.Timestamp.LocalDateTime
  $row.duration = $currentEvent.Fields["duration"].Value
  $row.logicalreads = $currentEvent.Fields["logical_reads"].Value
  $row.physicalreads = $currentEvent.Fields["physical_reads"].Value
  $row.EndResult = $currentEvent.Fields["result"].Value.Key
  $row.RowCount = $currentEvent.Fields["row_count"].Value
  $row.ObjectName = $currentEvent.Fields["object_name"].Value
  $row.writes = $currentEvent.Fields["writes"].Value
  $row.CPU = $currentEvent.Fields["cpu_time"].Value
  $row.event_name = $currentEvent.name
  $row.database_id = $currentEvent.Actions["database_id"].Value
  $row.hostname = $currentEvent.Actions["client_hostname"].Value
  $row.application_name = $currentEvent.Actions["client_app_name"].Value
  $row.login_name = $currentEvent.Actions["server_principal_name"].Value
  $row.spid = $currentEvent.Actions["session_id"].Value
  $row.xe_log_file = $fileName
  if($currentEvent.name -eq 'sql_batch_completed') {$row.text_data = $currentEvent.Fields["batch_text"].Value}
  else {$row.text_data = $currentEvent.Fields["statement"].Value}
  $dt.Rows.Add($row)
  }
  $cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(servername);Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AuditTest");
  $cn.Open()
  $bc = new-object ("System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $cn
  $bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 1200 #you can increase if required
  $bc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.xe_audit_collection"
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("server_name",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[0])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("xe_load_date",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[1])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("end_time",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[3])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("text_data",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[4])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("duration", $dt.Columns.ColumnName[5])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("logicalreads",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[6])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("physicalreads",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[7])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("EndResult",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[8])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("RowCount",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[9])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("ObjectName",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[10] )
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("writes",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[11])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("CPU",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[12])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("event_name",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[13] )
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("database_id",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[14])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("hostname",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[15] )
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("application_name", $dt.Columns.ColumnName[16])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("login_name",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[17])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("spid",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[18])
  [void]$bc.ColumnMappings.Add("xe_log_file",$dt.Columns.ColumnName[19] )
  $bc.WriteToServer($dt)
  write-host " $($dt.rows.count) Rows have been transferred to SQL Server destination"`r`n
  $cn.Close()
  $events.Dispose() 
  $result = "`n Loading of file $XEFilePath complete! `n"
  }
  Catch
  {
      $result = $_.Exception
      $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName

  }
  return $result
  }
  #### Load your First File #####
  $XEFilePath = "C:\Extended Event Audit Logs\RPC_competed and sql_batch_completed\RPC_competed and sql_batch_completed.xel"  ## file location
  $server = "(servername)"   ## server name, you are collecting XE data
  $XEFile = "RPC_competed and sql_batch_completed.xel"  ## XE File Name
  Shred-XElogs -filewithPath $XEFilePath -servername $server -fileName $XEFile
```

Here's the error message that I'm getting -

"Assembly not found.  Loading it from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\Microsoft.SQLServer.XEvent.Linq.dll"

"Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SQLServer.XE.Core, Version=12.0.0.0, Culter=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

I made sure the Microsoft.Sqlserver.XE.Core.dll file is stored in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared folder.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C# for this you don't need powershell.  This can be done by just querying the .xel file using `fn_xe_file_target_read_file` and then storing the results in a table.  The following example was based off a spinlock related extended event, and this drops the result table (if it exists) then creates it.  Of course you may want to modify this to either to not discard past results by removing the `DROP`/`SELECT INTO` or only `TRUNCATE` the table holding the results.

```
 string sqlQuery = @" if (OBJECT_ID(N'YourDatabase.dbo.XE_Output') is not null)
           begin
           drop table YourDatabase.dbo.XE_Output
           end

           select rf.object_name, 
           cast(rf.event_data as xml).value('(//data/text)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as SpinlockType,
           cast(rf.event_data as xml).value('(//data)[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') as SpinlockAddress,
           cast(rf.event_data as xml).value('(//data)[2]', 'nvarchar(250)') as Worker,
           cast(rf.event_data as xml).value('(//data/value)[3]', 'nvarchar(100)') as BackoffCount,
           cast(rf.event_data as xml).value('(//data/value)[4]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Duration,
           xp.name as Package, xp.description as PackageDescription, rf.file_name,
           cast(rf.event_data as xml) as EventInfo
           into dbo.XE_Output
            from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\Test\YourOutputFile.xel', null, null, null) rf
           left join sys.dm_xe_packages xp on rf.package_guid = xp.guid";


string connString = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=YourDatabase; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                sqlCmd.Connection.Open();
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
```

Comment: Hey userfl89, thanks for the info.  It doesn't matter to me how we do it, but I'd like to have it automated to where I don't have to manually load the audit table info.  That's why I was interested in using the solution outlined in the link I provided.  I was going to setup a SQL agent job that runs the PowerShell script nightly to import the results of the trace to the table.

Comment: Just making a job with a T-SQL script step that either inserts the results from fn_xe_file_target_read_file into the output table or (preferably) runs a stored procedure that does this would work. What I said before about removing the DROP/SELECT INTO would also apply to record data over time as opposed to between when the job runs. If the extended event is turned off, just make sure to update the query with the new file name before the next run or replace the file name with the path/file prefix plus a wildcard asterisk after the prefix/before .xel to return the contents of all the .xel files.